# dplyr: how to use mutate function to make a key combining a prefix string and a sequence of values

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

Working on a 4 rows data.frame object with dplyr, I want to created a new "id" column combining a prefix string and a sequence of values.

What I expected:

```
 columnA|columnB|columnC|id
 data    data    data    id-1
 data    data    data    id-2
 data    data    data    id-3
 data    data    data    id-4
```

What I tried:

```
 library (dplyr)
 y <- x %>%
        mutate (id =  "id- " & seq(from = 1, to =4, by = 1))
```

Comment: `x %>% mutate(id = paste0('id-', 1:4))` should do the job

Comment: @ProcrastinatusMaximus maybe you can turn it into an answer?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Either:

```
x %>% mutate(id = paste0('id-', 1:4))
```

or:

```
x %>% mutate(id = paste0('id-', row_number()))
```

or:

```
x %>% mutate(id = paste0('id-', 1:n()))
```

gives you what you want:

```
  columnA columnB columnC   id
1    data    data    data id-1
2    data    data    data id-2
3    data    data    data id-3
4    data    data    data id-4
```

---

Off course this can also be accomplished easily in base R:

```
x$id <- paste0('id-', 1:nrow(x))
```

It is better not to use `row.names` because they are not always numbers (see for example `row.names(mtcars)`).

---

Or using the `data.table` package:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(x)[, id := paste0('id-',.I)]
```

Answer (score 5):

You can do this one of two ways (of many I assume):

1) Using `dplyr` as follows:

```
df %>% mutate(id = paste0('id-', row_number()))
  columnA columnB columnC   id
1    data    data    data id-1
2    data    data    data id-2
3    data    data    data id-3
4    data    data    data id-4
```

2) Using simple base package assignment

```
df$id <- paste0('id-', row.names(df))
df
  columnA columnB columnC   id
1    data    data    data id-1
2    data    data    data id-2
3    data    data    data id-3
4    data    data    data id-4
```